# Generating test results and coverage reports in Jenkins, using Yeoman and Mocha

Tags: jenkins, mocha.js, yeoman

I am starting a new project, and investigating [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) and [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/) for use on the project. We use Jenkins for CI.

So far, I have figured out how to get client side testing working, but I am struggling to generate test results (and eventually coverage reports) that can be tracked by Jenkins. Has anybody successfully done this?

Answer (score 6):

The xunit reporter works well, for generating test reports.

Command line:

`mocha -R xunit | grep "<" > reports/mocha.xml`

With Jenkins, just 'publish JUnit test result report', it should work.

But, I'm still finding a solution to publish the coverage report.

Answer (score 4):

I have been able to add code coverage reports to my Jasmine tests using testem.
Testem seems to work with Mocha too.
https://github.com/airportyh/testem

Follow the instructions on the read me file. It explains how to use testem ci in continuous integration mode.

You will need to get the tap plugin - https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/TAP+Plugin - from jenkins.

Vytch

Comment: For test coverage if using testem, here is an example project using jscoverage https://github.com/richardbutler/testem-coverage-sandbox

Answer (score 0):

Not tested it, but depending on which test driver you're using (mocha, jasmine), it can be as easy as using the right reporter. See for example https://github.com/visionmedia/mocha/issues/83 for mocha.

Comment: client side mocha tests are running in PhantomJS. I haven't find a way to have it use anything other than the GruntReporter

Comment: So, turns out I can set the reporter in the index.html file that runs the tests, like this: <script>mocha.setup({ui: 'bdd',
                       ignoreLeaks: true,
                       reporter: mocha.reporters.JSON
                      })</script> But, then I get errors writing to stdout.